# After specific method other methods won't work

Tags: android, android-activity, methods, fragment

I've been working on an app that displays articles and shows the article's title on the toolbar and if I set the article text and toolbar text by calling the method from the article fragment on the main activity in the fragment's `onResume` method then it works fine, however as soon as I try doing it after calling a specific method within the fragment it just doesnt work giving me `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

I have tried changing everything and making the `refreshDisplay` method get called at different times and renaming and changing and completely removing the method input from `newClassArticle` and no matter what - no matter if I just use static strings, no matter if I don't even change the strings - after `newClassArticle` is called on the fragment, it will no longer execute the actions within `refreshDisplay` and will give the above error.

This is the `newArticle` method in the main activity:

```
public void newArticle() {
    frag_article newArticle = new frag_article();
    newArticle.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    FragmentManager fragManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.activeFrag, newArticle);
    transaction.commit();

    newArticle.newArticleClass(articles.get(0));
}
```

This is the `setActionBarTitle` method in the main activity:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

This is the `newClassArticle` method in the fragment:

```
public void newClassArticle(class_article newArticleClass){
        articleTitle = newArticleClass.title;
        articleBody = newArticleClass.body;

        refreshDisplay();
}
```

and this is the `refreshDisplay` method in the fragment:

```
public void refreshDisplay(){
        activity.setActionBarTitle(articleTitle);

        txtBody.setText(articleBody);
}
```

Any help on this infuriating issue would be welcome

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace or check which line is throwing the nullpointer error.

Comment: is txtBody a TextView for the fragment layout?

Comment: always try to right a brief post explaining what exactly is the problem that you are facing and don't include the history of things that no one wants to read!  If you are getting any exception posting stack-trace will be lot more helpful

Comment: Where is activity.setActionBarTitle come from?

Comment: Yes txtBody is a textView, setActionBarTitle is called from the fragment which allows you to select an article - but that part is not part of the problem as I've checked in my attempts to fix it.

And sorry but I couldn't figure out a better way to show the fact that there is a problem somewhere apparently.

And what do you mean by stacktrace? - The entire error readout?